Azure App Service Plan is also a security boundary?
I know that an Azure App Service Plan is mainly a way to configure the resources (vCPU-s, RAM, etc) for a set of Azure App Services. But is it also a security boundary?
In other words, if I host two different App Services in the same App Service Plan, is there any way that one app can access the settings or the data of the other app?


Azure App service plan has underlying VM's, CPU's and memory to store Web apps depending upon its SKU. It can act as a security boundary if you enable VNET Integration within the Web Apps to only communicate with the resources inside a VNET or Peered VNET.

The Web app inside Azure App service plan are isolated. If there's no VNET Integration enabled within the Azure Web app, You can ping and access the Web app via Azure SQL or other resources publicly. As there's no access restriction, Refer below:-



But if the VNET integration is enabled within the 2 Web apps, Those 2 Web apps can communicate with each other. Even Azure SQL within a VNET can be allowed in the Azure Web app VNET integration, This is one way of making the underlying Web apps inside Azure App service plan secure. Refer my SO answer for the same setup.

One alternative is to use Azure App Service Environment which act as an Isolated environment for your App service plans.

